# Show that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ the following equality is true $a^4-a^2>b^2-b.$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $2b>1$ and $a>\sqrt{b}$ the following equality is true:

$$a^4-a^2>b^2-b.$$

I started as follows

$$a^2(a-1)(a+1)-b(b-1)>0.$$

I do not know what to do with this. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That's the same as
$a^4-b^2 > a^2-b$
or
$(a^2-b)(a^2+b) > a^2-b$
which makes it obvious.

Just in case:

$a^2+b > 2b > 1$.